# Find the the value of

Tags: number-theory, functions

Given that $f(x)+3x f (\frac{1}{x})=2(x+1)$

Find the value of $f(101)$?

Comment: Is that $f(\frac 1x)$ in the expression?

Comment: What are the domain and the codomain of $f$?

Comment: Please tell us the domain and the codomain of $f$. Also for what values of $x$ the functional equation holds.

Answer (score 10):

Plug $x = 101$ to get: $$f(101) + 303 f\left(\frac{1}{101}\right) = 204.$$Plug $x = 1/101$ to get: $$f\left(\frac{1}{101}\right) + \frac{3}{101}f(101) = \frac{204}{101}.$$Solve the system: $$\begin{cases} f(101) + 303 f\left(\frac{1}{101}\right) = 204\\  \frac{3}{101}f(101)+f\left(\frac{1}{101}\right)  = \frac{204}{101} \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

You can easily reduce this to $$xf\left(\frac1x\right)=f(x)\tag 1$$

by making use of the transformation $x\to \frac1x$.  Then eliminate $f\left(\frac1x\right)$ from the original equation and solve for $f(x)$ to find ...

**SPOLIER ALERT:** SCROLL OVER TO SEE ANSWER

> $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{2}\implies f(101)=51$

Comment: @maya Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1):

Given $f(x)+3xf(\frac{1}{x})=2(x+1)$-->(1)

$replace "x" by "\frac{1}{x}"on both sides$

*And after replacing, just multiply it with" 3x " on both sides*

We get

$ 3xf(\frac{1}{x})+9f(x)=6+6x$-->(2)

```
Now substract (2) from(1)
```

$8f(x)=4x+4$

$=>f(x)=\frac{x+1}{2}$

```
Put x=101
```

$f(101)=\frac{101+1}{2}=51$

Comment: An error in the subtraction - $8f(x)=4x+4$

Comment: Yes I edited it thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may show that: 
$f(x)=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{5}{8}$ and than plug 101!

Comment: I am afraid that it is not correct $f(x)=\frac{x+1}2$ would be better.

Comment: You are right! Thanks